# Chrome causes Firefox to crash on 18.04

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

I'm not sure how to describe this. On Chrome 68.x everything is fine, but when I updated a couple of weeks ago to 69.x (and today to 70.x) this weird bug started happening. It's easy to reproduce:

1. Open Firefox, have a couple of tabs active.
2. Open Chrome
3. Go to Firefox, all tabs now show a spinner:

[image]

The only way to get out of it is by closing chrome and restarting firefox.

Anyone have any thoughts on how to debug this / get more information? My guess is it has to do with rendering changes in Chrome 69.x +

Interestingly Chromium works fine.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS, Gnome 3.28.2, Firefox is 62.0.3

Edit: I've tried installing both Chrome from the website  https://www.google.com/chrome/, I've tried installing it via the ppa, and ensuring that I purge it. I've tried both the stable and unstable branches. They all have the same issue.

Edit 2: Every crash corresponds with a crash report generated in Firefox as shown in about:crashes. I have no idea what these crash reports mean. I ended up filing a bug report for it here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1499824

Comment: I think that's a bug in Firefox itself. I have noticed it several times on my Ubuntu and even on Windows. But after 30-40 seconds of spinning Firefox is back to work. I have reported to Firefox around 5-6 times, but still no update regarding the same. In my case that's not a fault of Chrome.

Comment: Look for logging output from Firefox or Chrome. Perhaps it'll be in `~/.xsession-errors`. (If it's not there, then run them from the command line, and scrape what's on the terminal.) Is there anything related in `dmesg(1)` output?

Comment: As an update, it looks like this is an issue with fontconfig as detailed here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1495900